# PHP Mysqli request Url after a query is finished

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to request a URL Or api in PHP after  the fetch query is completed but am unable to do it

as my below api as follows

1.URL
2. Username Which will be by default which will not change
3. Password is also as same as username
4. Sender id is also as same as username and password
  **but Her every things matter the url should wait till the PHP result is Fetched**
5. Phone Number will be the PHP fetch result `$NumStr`
6. Text will be of our own
7. Priority & smstype will also be of our own which will not change

```
$query="SELECT  Num FROM euser WHERE UserId IN (SELECT ID FROM master WHERE          aa='aa' And cc='cc')" ;
$data=mysqli_query($mysqli,$query)or die(mysqli_error());
$Num = array();
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($data)){

   if($row['Num'] != '' && $row['Num'] != NULL){
      $Num[] = $row['Num'];
                              }
                              }
$NumStr = implode(',', $Num);


echo $NumStr;

mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

api
`http://test.forsms.com/api/sendmsg.php user=*******&pass=********&sender=*****&phone=&text=Test SMS&priority=Priority&stype=smstype`

TRY

```
$url = "http://test.forsms.com/api/sendmsg.php?user=".$usernamesms."sclage&pass=".$Password."&sender=".$Senderid." ID&phone=".$PhoneNumber."&text=".$text."&priority=".$smstype."&stype=".$priority."";
        header("Location: $url");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect to a URL, providing no 'output' has been sent to a browser, use a `header("Location: -URL- ");` replacing -URL- with your required URL string.

```
$url = "http://test.forsms.com/api/sendmsg.php user=*******&pass=********&sender=*****&phone=&text=Test SMS&priority=Priority&stype=smstype";
header("Location: $url");
exit;
```

Comment: was expecting the same thanks for the reply how can i add user data on the fields

Comment: @Shaik save each piece of data as a variable, and insert the variables into the URL string.  (Variables inside double-quoted strings will be parsed by PHP)

Comment: `$url="http:///test.forsms.com/api/sendmsg.phpuser=".$usernamesms."sclage&pass=".$Password."&sender=".$Senderid."ID&phone=".$PhoneNumber."&text=".$text."&priority=".$smstype."&stype=".$priority."";header("Location: $url");`   i tried like this but it dint work can u correct me where am i going wrong

Comment: `$url = "http:///test.forsms.com/api/sendmsg.php?user=$usernamesms&pass=$Pas‌​sword&sender=$SenderidID&phone=$PhoneNumber&text=$text&priority=$smstype&stype=$priority‌​";`

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '‌​' (T_STRING) in C:\`  gives me a error